# highlighting certain points on List Line Plot

Tags: plotting, marker

I have a list made out of points {x,y[x]} which I'm plotting using ListLinePlot.
I would like to highlight two point and plot a big dot (marker) on them with different color, lets take two point, for example, x=4 highlighted with the color yellow,  and x=20 with the color red.
The model:

```
n = 100;
f[x_] = x^0.5 + 4;
ListLinePlot[Table[{x, f[x]}, {x, 1, n}]]
```

Any help?

Comment: `ListLinePlot[Table[{x, f[x]}, {x, 1, n}], Epilog -> {AbsolutePointSize[6], Yellow, Point[{4, f[4]}], Red, Point[{20, f[20]}]}]`

Answer (score 3):

```
ListLinePlot[Table[{x, f[x]}, {x, 1, n}], 
 Mesh -> {{{4, Yellow}, {20, Red}}},
 BaseStyle -> AbsolutePointSize[10] ]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Or...

```
ListLinePlot[Table[{x, f[x]}, {x, 1, n}],
 Epilog -> {PointSize[.05], 
            Point[{4, f[4]}], 
            Point[{40, f[40]}]}]
```